# WPF: Copy from a DataGrid

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid

I would like to add Copy functionality to a WPF DataGrid.

1. The Copy option should appear in a right-click menu
2. It should copy the display text for the selected cell. (I am using read-only text columns.)

Answer (score 23):

In the DataGrid's `ContextMenu`, you can create a `MenuItem` and set the [`MenuItem.Command`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.menuitem.command%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) value to [`Copy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.applicationcommands.copy%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). It's a Command available through the standard [`ApplicationCommands`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.applicationcommands.aspx) list, so there won't be any additional code required to have it functional:

```
<DataGrid>
    <DataGrid.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem Command="Copy" />
        </ContextMenu>
    </DataGrid.ContextMenu>
</DataGrid>
```